# How are parameters passed from Qml to C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I would like to use call a C++ function from Qml in the following way:

```
Item{
        id: qmlItem

        function loadModel(dataModel)
        {
            // setup my listview
        }

        MyDataModel{
            id: model
        }
        Button{
            onClicked: {
                cpp.addValues(model)
                loadModel(model)
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in C++ I have the following function:

```
void myCpp::addValues(MyDataModel* model)
{
    // here I would like to add items to my data model
    model->addItem();
}
```

Now this would be possible if the model was passed as a pointer, but I am not sure if this is the behaviour of C++/Qml interaction. Would what I wrote work or there is another approach I need to use?

EDIT: I have compiled the program and it works fine. However, I would like to know what is going under the hood. I mean does QML sends parameters by pointer? Would the same approach work with a JavaScript array (instead of MyDataModel)?

Comment: Is `MyDataModel` a class defined in C++ that you registered with `qmlRegisterType`?

Comment: Yes (a subclass of https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__groupdatamodel.html)

Comment: Then i think your code is OK. Try running it, see if there are any errors and if the `model` you receive in C++ looks OK.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try defining your C++ function to take in a "const QJSValue &". You can extract a QObject * from that and downcast to your model. Also be careful about object ownership. Passing objects between the two can result in either leaking or the gc deleting what you don't want. I think what you have is fine, just be careful and read the Qt rules on it.

Comment: Ok the program does indeed work.

Comment: @DanielFeryance I am using Qt 4.8 so I cannot use QJSValue

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to use model for `ListView` which is passed from C++ you should look at the `QAbstractItemModel` or `QAbstractListModel`(maybe better and easier for your case) class from which you inherit and create your own model to use in the qml. To subclass `QAbstractListModel` from you'll at least need to reimplement `rowCount()` , `data()` methods, also you can reimplement `insertRows()` and `removeRows()` methods to dynamically add/remove data from model (which will also update the view automatically).
You should look up the http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractlistmodel.html or http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html
. Also, there were some easy examples in qtcreator on how to implement this kind of model

Comment: I don't need that since I am working on BlackBerry 10 and the built in model classes work fine